# Using material-ui with ecmascript6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I jus find [material-ui](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) and I'm trying to add some components in the following way

```
import React from 'react';
import mui from 'material-ui';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import PropertiesList from './../components/propertylist.jsx';
import Filters from './../components/filter.jsx';
import Properties from './../models/PropertiesModel.js';
import Toolbar from './../components/toolbar.jsx';
var AppBar = mui.AppBar;
var IconButton = mui.IconButton;
var NavigationClose = mui.NavigationClose;
var ThemeManager = new mui.Styles.ThemeManager();
var FlatButton = mui.FlatButton;
injectTapEventPlugin();


class TransProperties extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
     super(props);
   }

  render() {
    return <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-9">
            <AppBar
              title="Title"
              iconElementLeft={<IconButton><NavigationClose /></IconButton>}
              iconElementRight={<FlatButton label="Save" />} />
            <PropertiesList url="/properties.json"/>
        </div>
        <div className="col-lg-3">
            <Filters/>
        </div>
    </div>;
  }

   handleTouchTap() {
        alert("oh hi");
    }
}

export default TransProperties
```

but I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'spacing' of undefined`

which refers to

```
 getStyles: function getStyles() {
    var spacing = this.context.muiTheme.spacing;...}
```

What did I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're likely missing the [contextType](https://github.com/jkruder/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/app/components/code-example/code-block.jsx) on your component, which makes `muiTheme` available.

Your component should look something like this:

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {

  getStyles() {
    ...
    let spacing = this.context.muiTheme.spacing;
    ...
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={this.getStyles()} />
    );
  }
}

// Don't forget this little nugget
ExampleComponent.contextTypes = {
  muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback yeah it seems like this would be the way to do but I get Unexpected token

Comment: Can you post the component you're having trouble with? Maybe there's something else causing the `Unexpected token` issue?

Comment: I have it the link what you provide me helped a lot thanks!